# "Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity'" Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

I'm getting the following error:

```
> 02-06 23:10:24.104: E/dalvikvm(912): Could not find class
> 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', referenced from method
> com.robotium.solo.Waiter.getSupportFragment
```

When running a project I'm using for Programming Mobile Applications for Android Handheld Systems on Coursera.I believe this error is somehow related to my output answer being considered incorrect. if I can fix this error,I can fix my output.

I didn't have the latest version of Android Support Repository (not installed) when I initially ran my tests,but I now have the latest version of Android Support Repository according to the SDK Manager (v4),and have even restarted Eclipse and the emulator,but I'm still getting the error.

How can I fix the LogCat claiming ASR doesn't exist when it's installed according to the SDK?

Comment: do you have android-support-v4.jar in projects lib folder?

Comment: No, it isn't. What's the path I would copy it from to place into the project's lib folder?

Comment: you will find it at `android-sdk/extras/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar`. Copy it to your projects lib's folder. It will be added to your build path automatically.

Comment: I copied and pasted the android-support-v4.jar into the libs folder where robotium is, but it's still has the same error about it not being found. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: just try with clean and build. that is all you need as far as i know.

Comment: is it libs or lib folder?

Comment: libs, I have no lib folder...the error is gone. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll give you the marked answer points

Comment: its not lib folder its should be named as `libs`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If there is no "libs" folder then create one

then click

Project> Android Tools >Add support Library.

This will help you. Finally clean the project and restart Eclipse

Comment: On my machine I had to right-click the project, then select Android Tools > Add support Library in case that helps anyone.

Comment: When I'm tried above solution,I'm getting below error  Android Support Jar not found:] E:\eclipse-java-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\v4\android-support-v4.jar

Answer (score 12):

You need to add the support library **com.android.support:support-v4**

On Android Studio, go in the menu **File > Project Structure** (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S)
Select **app**, tab **Dependecies**, and in the **+** and search for the Maven libraries that you will use. In your case, the **com.android.support:support-v4**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either create a "libs" folder and put the "android-support-v4.jar" file

else

import the " android-support-v4.jar" to Android Private Libraries folder, and restart the IDE to take effect.

Answer (score -2):

Please Perform these two steps:
1)It's better to create libs folder and add "android-support-v4.jar" and dont forget to check checkbox mentioning "system library " .
2) Copy "android-support-v4.jar" from "adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/sdk/extras/android/support/v4" folder to your "/home/vinny/workspace/appcompat_v7/libs" appcompat libs folder.You can add "android-support-v7-appcompat.jar" this jar also to this folder from "adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/sdk/extras/android/support/v7"

Note: Don't forget to perform this step, properties->Android->Library-> add

Comment: adding jars to project is a bad practice. Instead, use gradle for dependencies

Comment: Its nor for Android Studio, commented for Eclipse errors