# Fragment is not being displayed in Android 4.4.4

Tags: android

I tried with support `Fragment` as well as normal `Fragment` but nothing is displayed on the screen when I call `launchAwesomeFragment()` in (Nexus7 4.4.4). But in other phones the `Fragment` launches perfectly.

There was no errors or anything in logcat but sometimes the following log appers when I call `launchAwesomeFragment()`. What might be the problem here?

> Could not find method
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState, referenced
>   from method .AwesomeFragment

Here's my code of `launchAwesomeFragment`

```
private void launchAwesomeFragment() {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, AwesomeFragment.newInstance());
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the app from the Nexus and testing it again? I've come across similar situations and usually a clean install solved it. Worth a try.

Comment: Make sure you're importing the support library version of FragmentTransaction (here) and Fragment (in AwesomeFragment.java).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, then you need to check if you've added the support library properly.

> Project > Android Tools > Add support Library

Now clean and rebuild the application and then uninstall and reinstall to try again.

If you're using Android Studio, then you might try clean and build. But in Android Studio, this is not an usual case. Anyway, you might take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26049978/3145960) here.

Generally these type of error log indicates the method is not found as the library is not referenced properly.

Hope that helps!